# Selecting items from table

Tags: usability, selection, deselection

With roughly the following layout it is intended users can search for items and select them. Except for some actions where deselection is natural (like Delete), actions preserve selection. Selection is preserved when search criteria are changed, so selection is understood more like "shopping cart": Users can apply whatever filter, manually select desired items, go to other pages, select, etc, until satisfied, after which they apply Action to a selected set. Due to the nature of the application, actions are almost never done on the whole search result set: Manual tuning almost always done by users. Table shows selected items with checked checkboxes (when those happen to be on current result page). As we deal with people, adding direct shopping cart metaphor is not desired.

However, some users are confused and make mistakes working on previous selection to which they add more.

Number of selected items and even confirmations on how many items action will be performed on are displayed clearly. Action buttons disappear when nothing is selected.

It seems like the mental model for this should be quite simple: selection control is explicit, selection persistent.

The question is, what is the problem? Can the current way be improved or should action-on-selection be completely different? Is it purely user interface issue, curable by adding some hints or fundamental usability flaw?

We probably can't redesign the whole thing quickly, so gradual improvement is preferable, but I just can't see any simpler way (wrt users mental model) nearby.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[image: mockup]

<sup>[download bmml source](/plugins/mockups/download?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fK9Lzc.png) – Wireframes created with [Balsamiq Mockups](http://www.balsamiq.com/products/mockups)</sup>

The first glaring issue for me is that the selected lines are still scattered throughout the table and [perhaps] out of the viewable area all together. I see that you are calling out "n persons selected" in a label above the table, but I don't think that is enough of a visual cue for some people, as we've seen evidenced in the failure rate of certain forms.

You should prioritize anything selected. When the user selects a line, duplicate the selection in a new section at the top of the table with a tinted background color and a clear title i.e. "Selected persons"

Comment: This is interesting approach. Where do you suggest to put actions then?